# Bind a char to an enum type

Tags: c++, coding-style, enums, char

I have a piece of code pretty similar to this:

```
class someclass
{
public:
enum Section{START,MID,END};
vector<Section> Full;
void ex(){
    for(int i=0;i<Full.size();i++)
    {
        switch (Full[i])
        {
        case START :
                  cout<<"S";
                  break;
        case MID :
                  cout<<"M";
                  break;
        case END:
            cout<<"E";
            break;
        }
    }
    }
};
```

Now imagine I have much more enum types and their names are longer....
well what i get is not a very good looking code and i was wondering if it possible to bind a specific char to an enum type and maybe do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<Full.size();i++)
    {
        cout<(Full[i]).MyChar();
    }
```

Or any other method that could make this code "prettier".
Is this possible?

Comment: You could always have an `std::map<Section, char>`, but I'm not sure that code would turn out to be cleaner with such a small set of values.  At the very least you could encapsulate the conversion inside of a function so that you can reuse it.

Comment: A `std::map` seems overkill here, a simple array suffices: `cout << "SME"[Full[i]]`. (That still needs improvements for manageability and safety.)

Comment: Might be a case for a #define header as well.  #define START 'S' ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not much you can do to clean this up. If you have access to the C++11 strongly typed enumerator feature, then you could do something like the following:

```
enum class Section : char {
     START = 'S',
     MID = 'M',
     END = 'E',
};
```

And then you could do something like:

```
std::cout << static_cast<char>(Full[i]) << std::endl;
```

However, if you do not have access to this feature then there's not much you can do, my advice would be to have either a global map `std::map<Section, char>`, which relates each `enum` section to a character, or a helper function with the prototype:

```
inline char SectionToChar( Section section );
```

Which just implements the `switch()` statement in a more accessible way, e.g:

```
inline char SectionToChar( Section section ) {
     switch( section )
     {
     default:
         {
             throw std::invalid_argument( "Invalid Section value" );
             break;
         }
     case START:
         {
             return 'S';
             break;
         }
     case MID:
         {
             return 'M';
             break;
         }
     case END:
         {
             return 'E';
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: The first solution seems great, unfortunately I don't have access to it.

Comment: I think you need `case Section::START:` etc.?

Comment: @aschepler No, you do not need to qualify the scope of a non-strongly typed global `enum`.

Answer (score 6):

In a situation like this you could be tricky and cast your chars.

```
enum Section{
    START = (int)'S',
    MID   = (int)'M',
    END   = (int)'E'
};

...

inline char getChar(Section section)
{
    return (char)section;
}
```

Comment: Well seems it would work but is it "legal"?
I mean does it considered good programing?

Comment: Is it legal, yes.  Is it good programming.. well without knowing exactly what your trying to accomplish I can't answer that.  It is prettier though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution in this case would be to use a map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
class someclass
{
    public:
    enum Section{START = 0,MID,END};
    map<Section,string> Full;

    // set using Full[START] = "S", etc

    void ex(){
        for(int i=0;i<Full.size();i++)
        {
            cout << Full[i];
        }
    }
};
```