# Enums and casting

Tags: c++, enums

This is my first time when it comes to casting and enums, so yea I came across this problem while trying to cast.

Assume I have the following enum

```
enum Region
{
A,
B,
C,
D,
};
```

and a function that reads a file that has a list of data

```
void loadData(castle &al3a, queue &q, float &c1, float &c2, float &c3)
{
    int i = 0;
    ifstream myfile;
    int n = 0;
    myfile.open("data.txt");
    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        myfile.close();
    }
    else {
        string line;
        while (!myfile.eof())
        {
            n++;
            getline(myfile, line);
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
    string line2;
    int T_Health;
    int T_Attack_N_Enemies;
    int T_Fire_Power;

    myfile.open("data.txt");
    myfile >> T_Health >> T_Attack_N_Enemies >> T_Fire_Power;
    getline(myfile, line2);
    myfile >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;
    getline(myfile, line2);
    int a,b,c,d,e,f;
    char g;
    enemy x;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 3; i++)
    {
        myfile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f >> g;
        x.ID = a;
        x.type = static_cast<Type>(b);
        x.time_step = c;
        x.Health = d;
        x.fire_power = e;
        x.reload_power = f;
        x.region = static_cast<Region>(g);
        enqueue(q, x);
        getline(myfile, line2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        al3a.towers[i].Health = T_Health;
        al3a.towers[i].attackEnemies = T_Attack_N_Enemies;
        al3a.towers[i].firePower = T_Fire_Power;
        al3a.towers[i].Tregion = (Region)i;
    }
    // shielded enemies have higher priority than ordinary enemies
    /*Priority(Shielded Enemy) = C1 * (EnemyFirePower / EnemyDistance) + C2 / (EnemeyRemaining time to shoot + 1) + EnemyHealth * C3*/
}
```

the data file should look something like the photo uploaded.
each row represents an Enemy, the first column is the ID,the second is the type,third is time_step,fourth is Health,anyways the last one is the region.
the queue somehow is implemented successfully but when I try to `cout<<enemyy.region` I end up getting 65 or 66.. etc pointing out to the ASCII code of A and B.. how do I cast the array to print out the A or B

P.S: type is also an enum with the same problem as the one stated prior

Picture:

[image]

Comment: How does `data.txt` content look like?

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that your file contains the characters A, B, C, D. These have no relation to the names you chose for your enum's values.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I uploaded an image

Comment: @molbdnilo I uploaded the file earlier, so you're saying the file must contain values 0-3 for it to work as I planned not the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your char variable contains 'a', it does contain an ascii value (97). You should not be casting such value to enum unless you know what you are doing. Enums in C++ are usually stored on 8 bits (which is the same size as size of char) (I am not sure if this is standardized)  so your x.region contains same value (ASCII) as your char g (that is why std::cout prints the ASCII value).

Doing enum cast is usually done only if your integral type is in enum's range (so if enum contains 4 elements, you should cast only integral values of range 0-3).

If you are interested in enum type behavior, you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159379/is-it-correct-to-cast-an-integer-to-enumerated-type) answer.

Moreover you should take a look at [c++11 enum classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095639/bind-a-char-to-an-enum-type) answer about mapping chars to enum class types, which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look on these stuff thanks alot :)